# PHP - date('DATE_RFC850') produces curious result

Tags: php, date

I tried to get the date with this constant, but instead of something like

> Monday, 15-Aug-05 15:52:01 UTC

I get

> MonAMPDTE_RJulyC850.

So it doesn't return a String but a Datetime or something, but then why does

```
$date = date('l, d-M-y H:i:s T');
```

Return exactly what I wanted (f.e.:Monday, 15-Aug-05 15:52:01 UTC)?

I'm just wondering why it returns different types on same input, because
DATE_RFC850 is just a string too: `const string RFC850 = "l, d-M-y H:i:s T"`.

Comment: `RFC850` != `DATE_RFC850`

Comment: Also, if it's a constant, it should be like `date(RFC850)` (without quotes)

Comment: Also you should pass it like variable to date function, but not like string in quotes

Comment: Relevant reading: [quoting constants in php: "this is a MY_CONSTANT"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1563654/2943403) and [Constants inside quotes are not printed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2937204/2943403)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use a constant, don't use quotes:

```
date(DATE_RFC850);
```

instead of

```
date('DATE_RFC850');
```

Answer (score 1):

RTM: http://php.net/date lists the acceptable formatting characters for a date. `DATE_RFC850` is not a valid formatting "string", except when considered as its individual components:

```
D - Mon-Sun
A - AM/PM
T - timezone, e.g. CST
E - not a valid char, used as literal output
_ - not a valid char, used as literal output
etc...
```

`'DATE_RFC850'` is a **STRING**. You want the constant, e.g.

```
echo date(DATE_RFC850); // note the lack of ' quotes
```

which does output your expected format:

```
Monday, 08-Jul-13 09:00:29 CST
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code,

```
<?php
echo date(DATE_RFC850); // you dont have to put it in quotes
?>
```

Output

```
Monday, 08-Jul-13 20:32:29 IST
```