# unable to get defined constant from app.php in cakephp3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to get a configuration from `app.php` for php `file(let say /webroot/1/2/getConf.php)`.

What I did was `$conf = require('../../../config/app.php');`
in `getConf.php`

then I got an error

> Notice: Use of undefined constant WWW_ROOT - assumed 'WWW_ROOT' in /config/app.php on line 44

So I debugged `$conf` and I got these

```
array (
'debug' => true,
'App' => 
  array (
    'namespace' => 'App',
    'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
    'base' => false,
    'dir' => 'src',
    'webroot' => 'webroot',
    'wwwRoot' => 'WWW_ROOT',
```

As you can see, I cannot get `WWW_ROOT` constant which should be defined in `paths.php`

Comment: What does your `config/app.php` file contain?

Comment: It contains <?php
return [
    'App' => [
        'namespace' => 'App',
        'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
        'base' => false,
        'dir' => 'src',
        'webroot' => 'webroot',
        'wwwRoot' => WWW_ROOT, 
        'fullBaseUrl' => false,
        'imageBaseUrl' => 'img/',
        'cssBaseUrl' => 'css/',
        'jsBaseUrl' => 'js/',
        'paths' => [
            'plugins' => [ROOT . DS . 'plugins' . DS],
            'templates' => [APP . 'Template' . DS],
            'locales' => [APP . 'Locale' . DS],
        ],
    ],

Comment: Where have you included `paths.php` to get the constant? From your code above you only appear to be including `app.php`.

Comment: If you're going to randomly include files from a CakePHP app in a not-CakePHP app - you're going to have a bad time. If you are/think-you-are actually using CakePHP you're doing something fundamentally wrong. You should ask how to do whatever it is you're trying to do (in whatever.php I need to ???) not how you tried to do it.

Comment: That's right!. I didn't include paths.php to get the onstant. Thanks!!!! @drmonkeyninja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [CakePHP's own class for](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/configuration.html) reading and writing to the `app.php` configuration.

If you want to [read](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/configuration.html#reading-configuration-data) a value from the config, you simply need to call `Configure::read($key = null)`.

> Used to read configuration data from the application. Defaults to
>   CakePHP’s important debug value. If a key is supplied, the data is
>   returned. Using our examples from write() above, we can read that data
>   back:

```
Configure::read('Company.name');    // Yields: 'Pizza, Inc.'
Configure::read('Company.slogan');  // Yields: 'Pizza for your body
                                    // and soul'

Configure::read('Company');

// Yields:
['name' => 'Pizza, Inc.', 'slogan' => 'Pizza for your body and soul'];
```

For [writing](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/configuration.html#writing-configuration-data) to the config file you would need to call `Configure::write($key, $value)`.

> Use write() to store data in the application’s configuration:

```
Configure::write('Company.name','Pizza, Inc.');
Configure::write('Company.slogan','Pizza for your body and soul');
```

**More Information**

- [Configuration](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/configuration.html)
- [Reading Configuration Data](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/configuration.html#reading-configuration-data)
- [Writing Configuration data](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/configuration.html#reading-configuration-data)

**Edit**

<s>To fix your error: When calling an [constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php) in PHP, you do not enclose it with `'` quotes, that's what's causing the error. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1563675/1604068).</s>

**Edit**

All of the changes made to the config are stored at runtime. To store changes please look into [Storing Runtime Configuration](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/configuration.html#storing-runtime-configuration) and [Creating or Modifying Configuration Files](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/configuration.html#creating-or-modifying-configuration-files).

Comment: `When calling an constant in PHP, you do not enclose it with ' quotes, that's what's causing the error.` - not true. They are referencing an undefined constant because they are including a config file from outside a CakePHP application (`let say /webroot/1/2/getConf.php`) when that happens an undefined constant is converted to a string of the same name.

Comment: Re-Reading the question, I probably misunderstood the entire question. I'll edit the question ASAP @AD7six

Comment: This is not what i wanted though, I wanted to use app.php outside Cakephp . Thank you for explaining in detail about this.

Answer (score 0):

@Eric Lee you need to define constants in `paths.php` file

path - `project->config->paths.php`

here you can define any constants and can retrieve in any controllers, and it`s for CakePHP 3.0 so please try this